# ¿ me pueden ayudar diciendo que hace cada linea del código por favor?

Tags: python

```
import random
 
def crearLista(N):
    L = [ ]
    for i in range(N):
        L.append(random.randint(0,100))
    return L
 
def CreaMatriz(N,M):
    Matriz = [ ]
    for i in range(N):
        Matriz.append(crearLista(M))
    for i in range(N):
        Fila = ""
        for j in range(M):
            Espacios = ' ' * (5-len(str(Matriz[i][j])))
            Fila = Fila + Espacios + str(Matriz[i][j])
        print (Fila)
    return Matriz
 
CreaMatriz(5,3)
```

Answer (score 2):

Python utiliza la indentación para saber hasta dónde llegan las funciones o los bucles, así que según tienes el código no funcionará.

Te cuento:

`import random`
importa la librería de nombre random. Entre otros genera números aleatorios.

`def crearLista(N):`
creas una función llamada crearLista a la que pasarle el parámetro N

`L = [ ]`
creas una lista de python llamada L, vacía. No podrá usarse fuera de la función.

`for i in range(N):`
repite tantas veces como indique N (que será int) lo siguiente

`L.append(random.randint(0,100))`
añadimos a L un número int aleatorio entre 0 y 100. Sale del bucle dada la indentación.

`return L`
devuelve L, es decir, el array con N números aleatorios.

`def CreaMatriz(N,M):`
creamos una nueva matriz, que recibe parámetros N y M.

`Matriz = [ ]`
nueva lista vacía

`for i in range(N):`
para cada uno en N ocasiones repetimos...

`Matriz.append(crearLista(M))`
Añadimos el valor generado (lista de M elementos) por la función crearLista

`for i in range(N):`
Repetimos para N veces

`Fila = ""`
creamos un string vacío

`for j in range(M):`
repetimos tantas veces como M

`Espacios = ' ' * (5-len(str(Matriz[i][j])))`
creamos una variable llamada Espacios que tiene tantos espacios como 5- longitud de la matriz i j (referencia que compruebas siguiendo el trazado de bucles FOR

`Fila = Fila + Espacios + str(Matriz[i][j])`
La fila (str vacío) concatena con el número de espacios correspondiente y le suma el string que hay en ese puesto de la matriz. Esto seguramente lo esté haciendo para que con los espacios se quede todo estéticamente en la misma parte de la "celda"

`print (Fila)`
Mostramos todas las "Fila" gracias a los FOR anidados

`return Matriz`
devolvemos la matriz completa

`CreaMatriz(5,3)`
llamas a la función CreaMatriz con esos parámetros

Comment: Voto positivo me refiero jaja